# Intersection of two subspaces is the span of the vector $b$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let the vectors $u_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$, $u_2=\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\\4\end{bmatrix}$, $v_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}$, $v_2=\begin{bmatrix}2\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^3$.
Let the subspaces be $U=\operatorname{span}(u_1,u_2)$, $V=\operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2)$

**1) Show that $U\cap V=\operatorname{span}(b)$, where $b=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$.**

My approach:
So $U$ is the span of the two vectors $u_1, u_2$, which is the linear combination of the vectors. So they span a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Which mean $U$ is the set of vectors on the following form:
$U=\{u=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha'+2\beta'\\2\alpha'+3\beta'\\3\alpha'+4\beta'\end{bmatrix} | \alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{R} \}$,

The same approach goes for $V$, so $V$ is the set of following vectors:
$V=\{v=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha+2\beta\\\alpha+2\beta\\2\alpha+3\beta\end{bmatrix} | \alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{R} \}$,

So $U\cap V$ is the set of elements contained in both $U$ and $V$. In that case I should find the $\alpha',\beta',\alpha,\beta$ where $u=v$.

Doing this creating a total matrix: $(u-v|0)$ I get the following equations:
$\alpha'+\alpha=0$, $\beta'-\beta=0$ and $\alpha+\beta=0$.

So honestly, now I'm a bit lost. I was hoping putting these equations back in the vectors v and u, that i would get some scalar ($\alpha',\beta',\alpha,\beta$) times the vector b: $k\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$, and then i could conclude that span was the linear combination of that one vector. But that only works for the vector v.

**Could somebody help me telling me why my approach is wrong, and what the best way of doing this?**

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more algorithmic approach.

We wish to find a basis of the intersection of $U=\operatorname{Span}\{u_1, u_2\}$ and $V=\operatorname{Span}\{v_1, v_2\}$ where
\begin{align*}
u_1 &= \left\langle1,\,2,\,3\right\rangle &
u_2 &= \left\langle2,\,3,\,4\right\rangle &
v_1 &= \left\langle1,\,1,\,2\right\rangle &
v_2 &= \left\langle2,\,2,\,3\right\rangle
\end{align*}
Let's start by inserting our vectors into the columns of a matrix
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|cc}
u_1 & u_1 & v_1 & v_2
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{rr|rr}
1 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 3 & 1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 & 2 & 3
\end{array}\right]
$$
The nullity of this matrix is the dimension of $U\cap V$. 
Row reducing this matrix gives
$$
\operatorname{rref}\left[
\begin{array}{cc|cc}
u_1 & u_1 & v_1 & v_2
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{rr|rr}
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
We immediately see that $\dim(U\cap V)=1$. Moreover, this reduced form tells us that 
$$
u_1-u_2-v_1+v_2=0
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
u_1-u_2=v_1-v_2=\left\langle-1,\,-1,\,-1\right\rangle
$$
This gives $U\cap V=\operatorname{Span}\{\left\langle-1,\,-1,\,-1\right\rangle\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind i figured it out. I made a mistake reading my equations from the total matrix. Instead of $\alpha' +\alpha=0$ It should be $\alpha' +\beta=0$